# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b839c9e1-1ee6-4e77-a05a-e862a0f9724c" retrofit

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to build a rest client using retrofit but the error I am encountering I am not sure what it is about:

```
    final String API_BASE_URL = APIURLS.API_BASE_WIZARD_URL;
    URI.create(API_BASE_URL);
    final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    final RESTApi wizardApi = retrofit.create(RESTApi.class);
    Response<List<Wizard>> response = wizardApi.loadWizards().execute();
    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        for(Wizard wizards : response.body()) {
            System.out.println(wizards.firstName());
            System.out.println(wizards.lastName());
        }
    //response.body().forEach(System.out::println)
    }else {
    System.out.println("response is null");  
}
```

so, i have tried to change the String id to double and have tried change it to int but it is still not working.

Here is the full print-out of error :

> Blockquote Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b839c9e1-1ee6-4e77-a05a-e862a0f9724c"
> at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
> at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:651)
> at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextDouble(JsonReader.java:909)
> at com.google.gson.Gson$1.read(Gson.java:319)
> at com.google.gson.Gson$1.read(Gson.java:313)
> at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)

Comment: `b839c9e1-1ee6-4e77-a05a-e862a0f9724c` is not a double. Which number should that be? It is either a String and it looks like a UUID

Comment: Seems like your `Wizard` class has a `double` field but the JSON actually contains a UUID for the same name.

Comment: OK. But when I changed the POJO fields to UUID type or String type, it is still giving me error.  How can I make things work ?

Comment: "still giving me error" <- which error? The same? That can't be, because why should a String be parsed as double?

Comment: Hi @knittl, I resolved the error by adding in one more lib - <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>